# How to load automatically SSH keys with passphrases in SSH agent

Tags: git, ssh, passphrase

I have one SSH key per git repository. I have repositories in Bitbucket and on Gitlab. I'm under **Ubuntu 18.04 LTS**. If i use those keys with `ssh-add` it works but i don't want to `ssh-add` all my keys and their passphrases each time. I want to do it one time at Ubuntu start at most. Here is the interesting part of my config, that i put in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` by despair to be sure that there are no rights problems :

```
AddKeysToAgent yes

Host git@bitbucket.org:mysthiq/blog.git
    UseKeychain yes
    HostName bitbucket.org
    PreferredAuthentications publickey
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/Blog/cle-ssh-linux
    IdentitiesOnly yes

Host git@bitbucket.org:mysthiq/guetzlifolder.git
    UseKeychain yes
    HostName bitbucket.org
    PreferredAuthentications publickey
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/GuetzliFolder/cle-ssh-linux
    IdentitiesOnly yes

Host git@bitbucket.org:mysthiq/portfolio.git
    UseKeychain yes
    HostName bitbucket.org
    PreferredAuthentications publickey
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/portfolio/cle-ssh-linux
    IdentitiesOnly yes

Host git@bitbucket.org:mysthiq/framework-cms.git
    UseKeychain yes
    HostName bitbucket.org
    PreferredAuthentications publickey
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/portfolio/cle-ssh-linux
    IdentitiesOnly yes

Host git@bitbucket.org:mysthiq/medoucine.git
    UseKeychain yes
    HostName bitbucket.org
    PreferredAuthentications publickey
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/medoucine/cle-ssh-linux
    IdentitiesOnly yes

Host git@gitlab.wexample.com:oef/contests.git
    UseKeychain yes
    HostName bitbucket.org
    PreferredAuthentications publickey
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/vinalies1.3/cle-ssh-linux
    IdentitiesOnly yes

Host git@gitlab.wexample.com:oef/mobile_v1.3.git
    UseKeychain yes
    HostName bitbucket.org
    PreferredAuthentications publickey
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/oef/mobile/cle-ssh-linux
    IdentitiesOnly yes

Host git@bitbucket.org:mysthiq/phpbench.git
    UseKeychain yes
    HostName bitbucket.org
    PreferredAuthentications publickey
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/phpbench/cle-ssh-linux
    IdentitiesOnly yes

Host git@bitbucket.org:mysthiq/prevandcare.git
    UseKeychain yes
    HostName bitbucket.org
    PreferredAuthentications publickey
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/PrevAndCare/cle-ssh-linux
    IdentitiesOnly yes

Host git@bitbucket.org:mysthiq/sfboilerplate.git
    UseKeychain yes
    HostName bitbucket.org
    PreferredAuthentications publickey
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/sfBoilerPlate/cle-ssh-linux
    IdentitiesOnly yes

Host git@bitbucket.org:mysthiq/sitesize.git
    UseKeychain yes
    HostName bitbucket.org
    PreferredAuthentications publickey
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/SiteSize/cle-ssh-linux
    IdentitiesOnly yes

Host git@bitbucket.org:mysthiq/vinalies.git
    UseKeychain yes
    HostName bitbucket.org
    PreferredAuthentications publickey
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/vinalies/cle-ssh-linux
    IdentitiesOnly yes

Host git@bitbucket.org:mysthiq/vinalies1.3.git
    UseKeychain yes
    HostName bitbucket.org
    PreferredAuthentications publickey
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/vinalies1.3/cle-ssh-linux
    IdentitiesOnly yes

Host git@bitbucket.org:mysthiq/vinciaprep.git
    UseKeychain yes
    HostName bitbucket.org
    PreferredAuthentications publickey
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/vinciaprep/cle-ssh-linux
    IdentitiesOnly yes

Host git@gitlab.wexample.com:wexample-public/scripts.git
    UseKeychain yes
    HostName bitbucket.org
    PreferredAuthentications publickey
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/Wexample/cle-ssh-linux
    IdentitiesOnly yes
```

If i can know a mean to test quickly my ssh config without having to reboot ubuntu each time i make a change, i'll  be happy too. (The goal is to use these projects with PHPStorm.)

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure but your SSH agent needs to know which SSH key to use for that particular repo and this can't be an automatic process due to security concerns. To re-initialize it with a different SSH key each time you can run this command `eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"` and after this add your SSH key for that repo `ssh-add <SSH-key-name>`. Using this way you need not restart your machine. Hope this helps.

Comment: I already use similar commands as of now but I restart my machine at least one time a day because this machine is not a server but my personal laptop so this does not help me :)